# Change iframes using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

**Hi guys!**
I have a line of code:

```
<iframe id="ChildFrame" class="_page_frame_style" src=""></iframe>
```

So I have three buttons (id: "one", "two", "three"). 
And I need to change src of iframe by clicking on respective id.
**Idea is:**
1. When page is loaded no frame is displayed. (display:none)
2. When click on "one" button - shows one.html.
3. When click on "two" button - shows two.html. And so on... 
4. Make a button to return ChildFrame into display:none.

I've been googling for it, but every try failed.
**Thanks for each reply!**

Comment: `function change(button){iframe.src=button.innerHTML+".html";}`and `<button onclick="change(this)">one</button>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the answer

```
$('#ChildFrame').attr('src', src_value)
```

and the src_value is the source link value that you want to set for your iframe element

and also have a look at this link:

https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/changing-and-loading-an-iframe-src-attribute-with-jquery/9571/2

Comment: Omg, it somehow works!)) Great thanks!)) p.s. I need to learn it

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the HTML `<iframe>` tag `src` attribute in JavaScript using `element.src`. Therefore, you can make a button that calls a function which makes the src of the `<iframe>` change each time.

Additionally, you can make the iFrame hidden by default and use JavaScript to display it again when the button is pressed.

```js
function changeIFrame(url) {
    document.querySelector("iframe").src = url;
    document.querySelector("iframe").setAttribute("style", "");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeIFrame('/page1.html')">Page 1</button>
<button onclick="changeIFrame('/page2.html')">Page 2</button>

<iframe style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

Comment: Could you, please, make a code? It's seems to be a lot of issues if I'd make it. ;)

Comment: The code above should work. Replace `/page1.html` and `/page2.html` with the pages you want to load in the `<iframe>`. Also, ensure there is only 1 `<iframe>` element in the `index.html` file to ensure the `element.querySelector()` works.

Comment: Here is a GitHub gist with an example project. https://gist.github.com/devision1088/fc8cc1c92eba3ff9b195c8a04c5c5830

Comment: dear devision1088, I've commented your git. Look, please ;)

Comment: because it doesn't change src

Comment: You script is in the head tag. It good practice to put the script in the body tag since putting it in the head tag will only make it run on load. Try moving the script to the body tag. Download the gist and open index.html to see the example.